# Выборка производителя с группировкой

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

у меня задание, вывести, какой склад чаще всего получал товары самого распространенного производителя. Есть запрос, но препод говорит, что это не правильно. Что нужно исправить?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Производитель 
FROM Размещение INNER JOIN Содержимое_заказа on Содержимое_заказа.Код_товара = Размещение.Код_товара INNER JOIN Товар ON Размещение.Код_товара = Товар.Код_товара
WHERE Содержимое_заказа.Код_товара IN 
        (select TOP 1 WITH TIES COUNT(Производитель) QWE
             from Товар INNER JOIN Содержимое_заказа on Содержимое_заказа.Код_товара = Товар.Код_товара
             group by Производитель
             ORDER BY QWE)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где фрагмент кода, который ищет "самого распространенного производителя"? PS. Понять бы ещё, что имеется в виду под этим термином...

Comment: Спрашивали склад - ты выводишь производителя.

Comment: ==Понять бы ещё, что имеется в виду под этим термином... == И что значит "чаще всего"

Comment: Имеется в ввиду, больше всего заказов на товары этого производителя. Это фрагмент кода самого распространённого производителя, а со складом сделаю потом